Stopping Apache from writing to stdout
I have a docker setup in which I have an Apache2 container directing traffic to a PHP container. In the PHP containers logs (docker-compose logs), 99% of the messages are something like
172.18.0.6 -  05/Nov/2024:18:00:29 +0000 "GET /dispatch.php" 200

This seems like an Apache2 access message if I'm not mistaken. So I'm confused why it's writing to the PHP containers stdout. On top of that, it's not valuable to me in prod, and so I tried changing my vhost config's LogLevel to warn, but nothing changed (which makes sense if it's an access log).
I'd like to figure out what's the source of this log, and stop it from writing to stdout (but continue to write to the file I have it writing to) in prod so my logs have more valuable data.
My vhost:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my_domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://api:9000/var/www/api/$1
    ProxyPassReverse ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://api:9000/var/www/api/$1

    <Directory /var/www/api/>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule !\.(css|jpg|js|gif|png|ico|eot|woff|woff2|ttff|svg|psd|html)$ dispatch.php

        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <FilesMatch "\.(png|jp?g|gif|ico|mp4|wmv|mov|mpeg|css|map|woff?|eot|svg|ttf|js|json|pdf|csv)">
        ExpiresActive on
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 days"
    </FilesMatch>

    ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /var/log/my_domain/%Y/%m/%d/error.log"

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog "|/usr/bin/cronolog /var/log/my_domain/%Y/%m/%d/access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>


Can't you simply redirect stdout to /dev/null when starting the http server in your container?

Also take a look at that finding: https://serverfault.com/questions/1083450/apache2-writes-to-dev-stdout-instead-of-var-log-apache2-access-log-using-dock
